# Can't launch aptana 3 after update

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I'm having trouble with launching aptana 3 after an update yesterday. 
Running on windows 7 64bit.
I get this error trying to launch:

> The aptana studio 3 executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a re-install with the latest version from the Aptana website, I didn't try this primarily because I feared all my settings would be gone (like the update did). Nothing to fear, I just needed to re-link my workspace.
All my preferences where still there.